# Delete element in C

Tags: arrays, c, file, pointers, malloc

I allocated a pointer to pointer in C in this way:

```
    double **dataset = (double **)malloc(CHUNK * sizeof(double *));
    
    if (dataset == NULL) {
        printf("Something went wrong in load_dataset(), memory allocation failed!");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < CHUNK; i++) {
        dataset[i] = (double *)malloc((d + 1) * sizeof(double));
        if (dataset[i] == NULL) {
            printf("Something went wrong in load_dataset(), memory allocation failed!");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Then I read from a file `CHUNK` points with which I fill the dataset.
After I process the first point I have to delete it from dataset and move back of 1 position every element. suppose that dataset contain pointer to pointer that point to 1-dimensional point with ids from 1 to 50. After some stuff, it should contain point from 2 to 50 (obviously it need a `realloc` at the end).

I tried this:

```
    CHUNK--;
    for (int i = 0; i < CHUNK; ++i) {
        printf("id: %.2f\n", dataset[i][0]);
    }
    printf("------------\n");
    memmove(dataset[0], dataset[1], CHUNK * sizeof(double *));
    dataset = realloc(dataset, CHUNK * sizeof(double *));
    if (dataset == NULL) {
        printf("Something went wrong in initialize_cluster(), memory allocation failed!");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < CHUNK; ++i) {
        printf("id: %.2f\n", dataset[i][0]);
    }
    printf("-----------\n");
```

It doesn't work. This delete the first element but doesn't move all the element. The print show:

```
id: 1.00
id: 2.00
id: 3.00
id: 4.00
id: 5.00
id: 6.00
id: 7.00
id: 8.00
id: 9.00
id: 10.00
id: 11.00
id: 12.00
id: 13.00
id: 14.00
id: 15.00
id: 16.00
id: 17.00
id: 18.00
id: 19.00
id: 20.00
id: 21.00
id: 22.00
id: 23.00
id: 24.00
id: 25.00
id: 26.00
id: 27.00
id: 28.00
id: 29.00
id: 30.00
id: 31.00
id: 32.00
id: 33.00
id: 34.00
id: 35.00
id: 36.00
id: 37.00
id: 38.00
id: 39.00
id: 40.00
id: 41.00
id: 42.00
id: 43.00
id: 44.00
id: 45.00
id: 46.00
id: 47.00
id: 48.00
id: 49.00
------------
id: 2.00
id: 3.00
id: 4.00
id: 5.00
id: 6.00
id: 7.00
id: 8.00
id: 9.00
id: 10.00 <------Here it seems to
id: 10.00 <------stop to move
id: 11.00
id: 12.00
id: 13.00
id: 14.00
id: 15.00
id: 16.00
id: 17.00
id: 18.00
id: 19.00
id: 20.00
id: 21.00
id: 22.00
id: 23.00
id: 24.00
id: 25.00
id: 26.00
id: 27.00
id: 28.00
id: 29.00
id: 30.00
id: 31.00
id: 32.00
id: 33.00
id: 34.00
id: 35.00
id: 36.00
id: 37.00
id: 38.00
id: 39.00
id: 40.00
id: 41.00
id: 42.00
id: 43.00
id: 44.00
id: 45.00
id: 46.00
id: 47.00
id: 48.00
id: 49.00
-----------
```

Comment: I have understood nothing.

Comment: what didn't you understand? The result must be that the first element is eliminated

Comment: @chqrlie points are d-dimensional, + 1 is the ids of each point. I have a dataset in a file that is something like point_id value_1 value_2... value_d

Comment: I think I got it: points are d-dimensional, you allocate `(d + 1)` elements because the first element is the ID. Printing this is as a float with 2 decimals is misleading.

Comment: `memmove(dataset[0], dataset[1], CHUNK * sizeof(double *));` I think you mean `(CHUNK - 1) * sizeof(double *)`, otherwise you move one more pointer than expected

Comment: @chqrlie, yes it my fault, i'll correct it. But anyway the problem is memmove seems not working

Comment: @DavidRanieri is my fault again, I omitted a line, at the beginning there is a ''CHUNK--''. I'm going to edit

Comment: @DavidRanieri: not only should it be `(CHUNK - 1) * sizeof(double *)`, the arguments should be `&dataset[0]` and `&dataset[1]` or equivalent expressions.

Comment: @chqrlie why `&dataset[0]` and `&dataset[1]` and not `dataset[0]` and `dataset[1]`

Comment: @LucaMarchio: because you are moving the contents of the `dataset` array. You could also write: `memmove(dataset, dataset + 1, (CHUNK - 1) * sizeof(*dataset));` Just like `realloc`, `memmove` and `memcpy` are confusing and error prone, even for savvy programmers I must admit, I recommend writing a loop instead, that will potentially outperform the `memmove` call: `for (int i = 0; i < CHUNK - 1; i++) dataset[i] = dataset[i + 1];`

Comment: Do you know if computationally is the same? In this sense should I use memmove or the for loop?

Comment: @LucaMarchio: you can accept the answer by clicking n the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

To update the dataset and drop the first point, you can move the pointers one position using `memmove` but your code is incorrect: you pass the addresses of the first 2 points, instead of the addresses of the pointers inside the array of pointers.

You should write:

```
    free(dataset[0]);  // free the first point
    memmove(&dataset[0], &dataset[1], (CHUNK - 1) * sizeof(*dataset));
    dataset[CHUNK - 1] = NULL;  // clear the pointer to avoid duplicate pointers
```

There is no need to reallocate the array, especially if you read one more point at the end (into `dataset[CHUNK - 1]`). If you are meant to reallocate the array, you should not consider reallocation failure an error:

```
    double **new_dataset = realloc(dataset, (CHUNK - 1) * sizeof(*dataset));
    if (new_dataset != NULL) {
        // realloc succeeded, use the new pointer
        dataset = new_dataset;
    } else {
        // realloc failed: the block was not reallocated and is still valid
        // keep using the original pointer
    }
```

Also be aware that after the shift there are only `CHUNK - 1` points available so the printing code must stop at `CHUNK - 1`. Using a variable for the number of points seems a better approach.

Note that just like `realloc`, `memmove` and `memcpy` are confusing and error prone, even for savvy programmers I must admit, I recommend writing a loop instead, that will potentially outperform the `memmove` call:

```
    free(dataset[0]);  // free the first point
    for (int i = 0; i < CHUNK - 1; i++) {
        dataset[i] = dataset[i + 1];
    }
    dataset[CHUNK - 1] = NULL;  // clear the pointer to avoid
```

**EDIT** from your comments and code update, it seems `CHUNK` is indeed a variable. It is confusing to use all capitals for variable names. All capitals are idiomatic for macros representing a fixed quantity, such as an array length.

Comment: @LucaMarchio: no there is no need to free `dataset`. Either `realloc` succeeded and the return value (possibly identical to `dataset`) must be used or it failed and returned `NULL` and the original value of `dataset` is still valid and can be used for the rest of the code. It is unlikely for `realloc` to fail at reducing the length of an allocated object, but the C Standard allows it.  Note that `realloc` is quite error prone and has caused many software flaws in the past 40 years.